# How can I create a coffee cream effect with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

Today I would like to create a coffee cup with the cream floral on it as a text by using Photoshop. It looks like you order a cup of hot cappuccino and the bartender will draw a flower with cream on the surface of coffee but now I want to make it like a text to present a tittle.

[image]

I just need to do the cream text effect, no need to draw the whole cup of coffee since i can't use some images. So anyone can tell me how to do this cream effect on Photoshop.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: Nice name! Honestly though the effect you're after is going to be pretty complicated to do. Props to anyone that takes the time to figure out a way to do it consistently and explains it.

Comment: Just tossing these out there: play with the SMUDGE tool and TWIRL filters.

Comment: Why are people down-voting this? Just because the effect they want to achieve is harder than some of the other ones people have asked doesn't seem like a good enough reason to me. A majority of questions on here are tutorials for achieving an effect such as "thought bubbles", "reflections", "images in clouds" and so on. Not sure how this is any different. Could someone that down-voted explain why.

Comment: I down-voted. Question shows no effort. Even when asked, no effort is shown. To quote someone on meta - "If someone comes here for a solution, they should put as much effort into their question as others will put into their answers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also agree that Liquify, combined with the Smudge tool is going to be your best bet for this result. And keep in mind that it's all about the details and effort that you put into it to help determine the realism of the effect. And for the Liquify, I would say to try doing it with about 5 or 6 steps, starting from the larger ones first to get more of an overall shape, then bring it down to the smaller brush sizes for some of the edges.

Answer (score 5):

Why is this question downvoted so much?

Depending on your skills as an artist, I think you could get some good results messing around with the Liquify tool (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Windows). Add some drops of white onto a cream background and smudge away. This is what I came up with in under a minute, starting from a soft ball of white:

[image: minute work]

Answer (score 1):

Play with blur, opacity, and a little hand work to connect the letters. For best results, I would do everything with hard edges (type and and modifications) then apply the blur and opacity changes to everything at once for consistency throughout the effect.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve a similar effect using a solid coffee background, some added blobs of cream with the pencil tool, and liquify.