# How to achieve this coffee powder photo effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

I am interested in how to achieve this coffee cream/powder effect using Photoshop.

I have spent quite some time trying to figure this out, but wasn't successful. Using a clipping mask to apply texture works on very simple logos or text, but not on photos or anything that requires detail.

[image]

Comment: Just a greyscale photo tinted then set to multiply and opacity reduced a little. All the texture is from the cup photo simply showing through the overlaid portrait.

Comment: This question was marked as duplicate but it's actually different from [the one linked](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-can-i-create-a-coffee-cream-effect-with-photoshop), so I've reopened it.

Comment: No effects are needed. There are commercial coffee printers available for this purpose. just feed the photo via a smartphone application or stand in front of the coffee machine's camera. Make a web search for coffee-, capuccino- and latte printers. There are so many that I do not believe they all are bad jokes. Unfortunately I haven't seen one. Here are no coffee automates.

Comment: The post is 5 years old, so there is a chance coffee printers were not "that common".

Answer (score 2):

"You're thinking about this," as they say, "the wrong way."

This isn't created by applying a texture to the photograph of the people, but by overlaying the photograph on an already-existing texture (the cappuccino).

The entry-level method is to place the photo on a layer above the coffee, change its Blend Mode to Luminosity and lower the opacity a bit, then mask out the parts that don't belong.

This can be finessed in different ways to better "sell" the effect.

- Better color can be achieved with a Black-and-White conversion of the photograph, toned to a coffee hue and applied in Overlay, Color Burn, Darken or Multiply mode.
- Surface Blur applied to the photograph would help give it a more "drawn on the surface" look.
- A displacement mask created from the coffee image, applied to the photograph using `Filter > Distort > Displace...` could be used to modify the photo so it distorts to conform to the texture of the coffee.